# Same app name on iTunes not allowed after deleting old app which has same name too?

Tags: itunes

I deleted my app which has name "xyz" on one account and is not available on iTunes. Now I want to use that same app name "xyz" with different account on iTunes, but I am getting error as "The App Name you entered has already been used".